# Faux Columns - IE vs Chrome - Different opacity?

Tags: css

I don't know how to explain to you the trouble by using faux columns. So I'll [show](http://img607.imageshack.us/f/chromevsie.png/) it to us.

IN the first image you can see the faux columns rendered by Chrome. In the second by IE8. How you can see, on IE there is a different opacity, and i don't know why.

This is the HTML code :

```
<div class="commentsWide">
    <div class="commentContent">
        <div class="commentsWide1">
            <a class="lblackbbu" href="index.php?explore=userview&userv=chevr">chevr</a>
        </div>

        <div class="commentsWide2">
            side A sorry i forgot to mention :P                         
        </div>

        <div class="commentsWide3">
            <div class="commentsWide3A">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="commentsWide3B">11:06:20</div>
            <div class="commentsWide3C">30-06-2010</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this the CSS :

```
.commentsWide{width:690px; float:left; background-color:#999999; color:#000000; border-bottom:1px #000000 solid; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;}
.commentContent{width:690px; float:left; background-image:url(../img/comments_background.png);}
.commentsWide1{width:120px; float:left;}
.commentsWide2{width:450px; float:left; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;}
.commentsWide3{width:100px; float:left; text-align:right; font-weight:bold;}
.commentsWide3A{width:20px; height:35px; float:left; padding-left:10px; padding-top:5px;}
.commentsWide3B{width:70px; float:left; text-align:right; font-size:14px;}
.commentsWide3C{width:70px; float:left; text-align:right; font-size:12px;}
```

Why this happens? And how can I fix this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the `.commentContent` style has a PNG `background-image` which [IE8 still doesn't get right](http://www.mezzoblue.com/archives/2010/05/20/ie8_still_fa/).

Comment: Yeah! In fact if I use a .jpg image this trouble will vanish! Damn IE... :)

Comment: It might be possible to use a PNG if there is no alpha channel; that might make IE happy! If that still doesn't work it might be wise tojust remove the background-image on the .commentContent or like you mentioned, use a different image type.